# How to map a nested JSON object response in Angular 9

Tags: angular, mapping, angular9

Hi I'm beginner to angular and currently I'm using angular 9.I have a registration page that sends registration details to my nodejs and getting a json object request.The request is in following structure

```
    {"data": {
"_id": "",
"permissionLevel": 4,
"guestUser": null,
"user": {
  "resetPasswordToken": null,
  "userPaymentOptions": [],
  "_id": "",
  "email": "",
  "password": "",
  "displayName": "",
  "phoneNumber": "",
  "permissionLevel": 4,
  "createdDate": "",
  "__v": 0
},
"token": "",
"__v": 0}, "message": "Registered user is successfully created.","meta": {},"error": null}
```

I was able to get the request to my angular code but I need to get only the token. How can I map this nested object.Here is my angular code so far. Please help.

```
  register(email, displayName, password, phoneNumber){
return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + '/users/register', {email, displayName, password, phoneNumber})
  .pipe(map(user => {
    // store user token in local storage
    localStorage.setItem('currentRegisteredUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    console.log(user);
    this.currentRegisteredUserSubject.next(user);
    return user;

  }));}
```

Comment: just use `data.data.token` inside subscribe block `.subscribe(data => console.log(data.data.token);)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `data.data.token` inside subscribe block

```
service.register(...).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data.data.token);
}
```

this way you should get your token